# I can't access a key from a JSON response but can see all its keys

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, ajax, dictionary

Moral of the story: Always double check your keys. My key was `states` and was trying to access `state`

The Server is using Flask and responds a nested JSON.
On the front-end, I can see that the request went through and I can console.log the JSON just fine.

If I run:
`Object.keys(JSON)` it prints all the first keys.

Similarly, if I print out the JSON it will print it out as a JSON.

I have checked to make sure that the response is received a JSON, by using typeof().

Whenever I try to access a value in the JSON using an existing key, counties for example, it won't work.

If you notice below, `counties.cases` exists but when I try to access JSON.counties.cases it complains that counties doesn't exist. I have tried every single key.

And have tried to iterate through the JSON and every iteration returns `undefined`.

I have also tried `JSON.parse()` and it doesn't parse because it is already a JSON object.

[image: JSON Error]

```
    send_request = async () => {
        const host = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ":8080"
        const url: string = `${host}/get-all-data`
        let response = await fetch(
            url, {mode: 'cors'}
        ).then(response => response.json().then(res => {
            console.log(res) // Works
            console.log(res.state) // Doesn't work
            console.log(res.state.cases) // Doesn't work
}
```

Comment: can you add the code where you log the said JSON?

Comment: Did you name your variable with the reserved word JSON?

Comment: @Japsz I just added it.

Comment: @MisterJojo no it's called response, which is the JSON response.

Comment: It's likely `states`, not `state`, on your console.log

Comment: Looks like a typo to me, `state` vs `states`

Comment: Guys I love you and I'm so sorry! Giving ya'll a +1. It was a typo. And i was on it for 2 hours wow

Comment: you are missing a `)` on  `).then(response => response.json().then(res => {` ->  `).then(response => response.json()).then(res => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo on the key that I was using to access the JSON. So when I printed the JSON, it was printing fine but when I accessed `state` it wasn't working because the real key was `states`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to access an object that it is not there yet.
I mean, I think there is a `Promise` not resolved yet at the momento you are accessing the fields.

And at the time you open the object in the inspector, the promise is resolved and the result is there.

Whatever you are using to do the request in the browser, I presume it is returning that `Promise` and you need to wait for it to resolve before accessing the result.

Assuming you have your response promise in a variable `p`, you are able to wait for it doing something like:

```
p.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.countries);
});
```

If you need more details please let me know, or add some other info of your specific case.

Comment: The code indicates the promise is being handled correctly.

Comment: True, thanks! I answered before he added the handling code.